# How do I connect to oracle apex database through JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, oracle-apex

I have got a workspace in apex.oracle.com , Now , I want to connect to that database through JDBC from ubuntu-14.04 machine. please explain the steps , From where should I download the drivers and what should be the arguments in

```
DriverManager.getConnection();
```

step by step please. Thank you

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/84408/1822

Comment: There is nothing special about an "APEX database". It's just a simple JDBC connection. Any JDBC tutorial will tell you how to do that, e.g. the JDBC tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html The Oracle manual for the JDBC driver also explains how to establish a connection: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#JJDBC28058 and finally Oracle's FAQ for the JDBC driver also explains this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#05_01

Comment: I don't know what should be the argument of the function getConnection(), can you please tell me? I mean what is the drivertype ? And I also don't know what version they use in the web

Comment: Please go through the tutorials I gave you. If your code fails, come back, add your code and the error message and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to connect to the database that's supporting the APEX instance on apex.oracle.com. If you are hosting your own instance, it's no different than connecting to any other Oracle database.A quick code snippet can be found here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/TestOracleJDBCDriverInstallation.htm. You will need a password for the user/schema that you wish to connect to. If you don't have one, then talk to your DBA.

BTW, please remember that no production-type application and data should be used on the public APEX instance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is (or was) that you cannot connect via JDBC using the users you administered in your APEX workspace.

It seems to me that APEX users are not regular users for DB connections via JDBC. If my assumption is right, then you need to create database user with sufficient privileges to access the workspace tables.